# Updating columns using lapply

Tags: r

Assume I have a set of dataframes named N01 to N99. They are identical in structure and all have a column named DATE.

Assume this DATE column is of `factor` class and I want to change it to `POSIXlt`. If I intend to update the `NXX$DATE` column using a function like `strptime()`, how can I do so for all N01-N99 dataframes?

I've tried using `lapply` but have trouble using `assign` in the function to assign to a specific column.

For example, this didn't work:

`lapply( ls(pattern="N[0-9][0-9]"), function(x){ assign(paste(get(x),'$DATE',sep=''), strptime(get(x)$DATE),"%y/%m/%d), envir=.GlobalEnv)})`

I also tried assigning to `paste(x,"['TIME']")` too, but it also created a new data.frame instead of updating the column.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: In this case, I would be tempted to use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: @R. L. With `lapply` I think you could use `list2env` ie. `list2env(lapply(mget(ls(pattern="N[0-9]+")),....), envir=.GlobalEnv)`

Comment: thanks for both comments. I will try out the suggestions.

Comment: I am not sure the `lapply` is going to be any quicker. It certainly is a lot harder to work out what is going on if you use `lapply`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `lapply` with `list2env`.  But, you could do all the necessary analysis within the `lapply` and save each `list` element to separate file without even changing the original dataset using `list2env`.

```
lst <- mget(ls(pattern="^N[0-9]+"))
list2env(
        lapply(lst, function(x) {x$DATE <- strptime(x$DATE, "%Y-%m-%d") #change here
                                          x}),
                                          envir=.GlobalEnv)    
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>

 str(N01)
#'data.frame':  5 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ DATE: POSIXlt, format: "2012-01-01" "2012-01-02" ...
#$ val : num  -0.212 -1.042 -1.153 0.322 -1.5
```

#### data

```
set.seed(25)
N01 <- data.frame(DATE = factor(seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), length.out=5, by=1)), val=rnorm(5))
N02 <- data.frame(DATE = factor(seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), length.out=5, by=1)), val=rnorm(5))
N25 <- data.frame(DATE = factor(seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), length.out=5, by=1)), val=rnorm(5))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Instead of writing to `x$DATE`, it overwrites the `x` dataframe (i.e. x becomes just a single vector of date values). Not sure why.

Comment: @R. L. Have you tried the example I posted?.  The results I am getting is a 2 column data.frame as showed in `str`

Comment: I tried it on my dataframes and it overwrote all my dataframes instead of writing to the specific DATE columns

Comment: @R.L. I couldn't replicate the problem here.

Comment: hmm that little `x` fellow gave an `unexpected symbol` error. thanks for the prompt replies btw.

Comment: @R.L. may be copying and pasting the code directly to console have some side-effects.  Try to paste it on a text editor first

Comment: I know what's wrong. My weak understanding of R syntax. Because I was typing everything in a single line, I should have added a semi-colon before the `x` fella. It works now, thanks!

Comment: It works now, but could you elaborate on why the `x` is needed in the function? Thanks.

Comment: @R.L. Glad to know it works.  I also do type everything in single line with semi-colon. Then, when I paste it here, I do sometimes use `formatR` which removes the semi-colon and formats in a nice readable way.  In this case, I manually removed the semi-colon and split it to a couple of lines for easy readability

Comment: @R. L. Here `x` specifies each of the `datasets`.  If you don't return x after the `x$DATE`, it returns only that column.  To avoid, use either `return(x)` or simply `x`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution

```
# collect data frames into a list using mget
dats = mget(sprintf('N%02d', 1:99))

# loop through list of data frames and convert factor to date
dats = lapply(dats, function(x){
  x$DATE = strptime(x$DATE, "%y/%m/%d")
  return(x)
})
```

Comment: how do it break `dats` back into dataframes?

Comment: why would you want to break it back into dataframes? it is easier to deal with it as a list of data frames.

Comment: @R.L. - you don't. If as you say you have "_a set of dataframes named N01 to N99. They are identical in structure_", then that is ideal for `list()` operations. Lists collect data you want to store together and facilitate doing the same operation to each piece of data. It's more reliable, quicker, and simpler. E.g. - you name your list `N` and then `N[[1]]` retrieves dataset 1. `lapply(N, function(x) ...)` will apply a function to every dataset in `N`. `lapply(names(N), function(x) write.csv(N[[x]],file=x)` will write out a separate csv file for every dataset you have. No loops, no fuss.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I get what both of you mean now. In my case, while the datasets are the same in structure and name in order, they belong to different experiments. I guess I can just create different lists in that case.